# how to retrieve sheet names into dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
DataTable dtExcelSheetName = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
string getExcelSheetName = dtExcelSheetName.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + "]";

ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();



foreach (DataRow row in dtExcelSheetName.Rows)
{
    aList.Add(row);
}       
drpSeletSheet.DataSource = aList;
for (int i = 1; i < dtExcelRecords.Rows.Count + 1; i++)
{
    drpSeletSheet.Items.Add(dtExcelRecords.Rows[i]["Table_Name"].ToString());
}
drpSeletSheet.DataBind();

objAdapter1.SelectCommand = cmd;
objAdapter1.Fill(dtExcelRecords);
```

Comment: Do not use `ArrayList`. Use `List<DataRow>`.

Comment: clarify with what your error is please